# Javascript document.getElementsByClassName not returning all elements

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code (pure js, no libs), however when its run it only returns one element instead of two

```
function changeButtonStyles() {
    var actualButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("read-more");
    for (var i = 0; i < actualButtons.length; i++) {
        actualButtons[i].parentNode.className = "basic";
        actualButtons[i].className = "btn btn-xs btn-default";
    }
```

It should return two elements from the page so I can modify them both, but it only returns the one or the loop only iterates through one. Why is this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzdkr2gL/1/)

Comment: well you change its initial class so after the click on the top link the function is executed once and then after the click on the bottom link the function doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try select all elements by method

```
document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
```

I update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rzdkr2gL/7/

And you can use `forEach` method

```
actualButtons.forEach(function (el) {
    el.parentNode.className = "basic";
    el.className = "btn btn-xs btn-default";
})
```

or (recommended way)

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(actualButtons, function (el) {
    el.parentNode.className = "basic";
    el.className = "btn btn-xs btn-default";
})
```

or

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach.call(actualButtons, function (el) {
    el.parentNode.className = "basic";
    el.className = "btn btn-xs btn-default";
})
```

Final code may be looks like https://jsfiddle.net/rzdkr2gL/8/

Comment: This works because `querySelectorAll` doesn't return a live collection.

Comment: Also note that [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) isn't supported on IE or Safari.

Comment: @4castle specifically IE8 and below, partially IE9. But works from IE10 and upward http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach

Comment: `actualButtons.forEach(...` won't work in any browser because `actualButtons` isn't an Array.

Comment: @starcorn Right, that's for an array. I was talking about [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Comment: Look `Array.prototype.forEach` support IE9 and Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rzdkr2gL/9/ Click the `change buttons` link.

Comment: @squint Have you tried it? It works for me.

Comment: Ok we can use NodeList.prototype.forEach =)

Comment: @4castle: Are you saying that if you visit the jsfiddle link in the comment directly above yours, and you click the `change buttons` link, you don't get an error? If so, what browser?

Comment: @squint I'm using Safari Mobile on my phone.

Comment: @4castle: Interesting. Firefox doesn't have it. ...but I see that Chrome does. That's good news. I need to check if it has been standardized.

Comment: @squint try in Firefox https://jsfiddle.net/rzdkr2gL/11/

Comment: @DmitriKorchemkin: Yes, that works because the `Array.prototype` iteration methods are generic. The direct call isn't available in Firefox yet, and I don't see it in the standard, but it would be nice if it made it in.